# Child Dynamic Height with Fixed Parent Height

Tags: css

I have a parent element with a fixed height, with 2 child elements.

The first element is dynamic in height, according to its content (or collapsed nature).

I want the 2nd element to be as high as it can be, until reaching the end of the parent's height. The trick is, I want it to be scrolled if it has more content than its height.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/929/) demonstrating this. Notice the 2nd section is cut - I'm trying to get it to scroll. Of course I can have `overflow: auto`, but I want only the child div to scroll, **and not the entire parent**.

I solved this with Javascript and it worked fine.
However, due to some glitches and animations, it didn't look all that smooth.

I tried searching for a CSS only solution, but nothing I did came close to solving this. Is there a way, or am I bound to dynamic calculations in JS ?

```
.parent {
     max-height: 250px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Edit**: Fiddle had incorrect link, fixed now.

Comment: Please add some code to your question to clarify your question.

Comment: Given your rep, you should know that this question is on its way to get closed, because there is no code at all from you.

Comment: @dippas Updated with what I could, hope it helps.